# What is meant by this php statement

Tags: php

Hello I have read following php statement from a blog but I am unable to understand its meaning. Is it treated as if condition or any thing else? Statement is

```
<?= ($name== 'abc' || $name== 'def' || $name== 'press') ? 'inner-pagehead' : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Look up the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read this as:

```php
if($name=='abc' || $name=='def' || $name=='press') {
  echo 'inner-pagehead';
} else {
  echo '';
}
```

The `<?=` is the [`echo()` shortcut syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), then the `(test)?true:false;` is a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that if $name is any one of those 3 values ("abc","def", or "press"), then display the text "inner-pagehead". Otherwise, don't display anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would call a poorly written Ternary condition.  it basically echos `'inner-pagehead'` if the `$name` variable matches any of the three conditions.  I would have done it like this:

```
<?php
    echo in_array($name, array('abc', 'def', 'press')) ? 'inner-pagehead' : '';
?>
```

Or, even better:

```
// somewhere not in the view template
$content = in_array($name, array('abc', 'def', 'press')) ? 'inner-pagehead' : '';

// later, in the view template
<?php echo $content; ?>
```